# Why is IDA Pro in batch mode slowing down during runtime?

Tags: runtime, batch-processing, disassembly, ida

I am running IDA Pro in batch mode on a Windows machine (idaw64.exe). executing the following command line very often to analyse a lot of files.

```
idaw64 -c -A -Smatcher.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

I need to disassemble the input file and run the script *matcher.py* on this disassembled files. The execution of this task works fine and I get the expected results.

But as I need to execute this procedure (disassembly + script) very often (ca. 40.000 times) I am caring a lot about runtime of one procedure. The execution slows down from 10s to 2min for one procedure, whereas the disassembled files do not really change and the script also remains the same.

What causes this slow down? How can I speed it up?